# NSScrollView scrolling issue

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to add link attributes to the NSMutableString of a `NSTextView`.

Since I only want to add the link to the visible text with the text view, I observe the `NSScrollView` for scrolling changes with the `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification` notification of the `NSScrollView`'s contentView.

When the notification selector is called, I add a link attribute to the string. But unfortunately the notification is called immediately after I've added the link attribute to the string. And this goes on and on forever - since adding the link changes the view's bounds.

Is there anything I miss here? Is this a Lion only issue?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like normal behavior. Why not just subclass NSScrollView, override scrollWheel: and post your own notification?

Comment: scrollWheel: is only called when the user scrolls the wheel of the mouse or with the trackpad. I think scrollClipView:toPoint: would be better.